Timescaledb drizzle connection - FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for roles with the SUPERUSER attribute
Im trying to connect to timescaledb, which has a session based pooler on top of, but I keep getting FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for roles with the SUPERUSER attribute
So I was looking at few places, got a bit confused by Pool from node-postgres and what is the actual usage of it.
Currently I have

import type { Connection } from './postgres.connection';
import type { Options } from 'postgres';

import postgres from 'postgres';

export const timescaleConnection = async <T extends Connection = Connection>(
  options?: Options<T>,
) => {
  const databaseUrl = process.env['TIMESCALE_DATABASE_URL'] ?? '';

  return postgres<T>(databaseUrl, {
    idle_timeout: 20, // 20 seconds
    ...options,
  });
};

What should I be doing? Using Pool or any other method of configuration?

The immediate fix is to increase the config setting max_connections. You can still connect as superuser (as indicated by the error message.)
But the setting only takes effect after restarting the Postgres server - which, of course, closes all connections. A connection pooler will open new ones as soon as the server is back online.
Or close some (idle?) connections.
You can kill process on the server, or more elegantly, use pg_terminate_backend() from within.
Get an overview with the system view pg_stat_activity.
To properly fix, determine a sane maximum for the number of connections, and configure your connection pooler accordingly, i.e. well below the set maximum to leave some as reserve.
See:

psql: FATAL: too many connections for role
Query a parameter (postgresql.conf setting) like "max_connections"
PostgreSQL Evolutions: "PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already"


with pg_bouncer in front of, shouldn't it be closing those connections for me?

pg_bouncer has a maximum of allowed connections that it will manage for you. So it helps your cause. Either pg_bouncer was configured with too many allowed connections, or max_connections is too low, or you have additional connections bypassing your connection pooler. pg_bouncer is just another client opening connections.

@PlayMa256 No, pgbouncer doesn't close the connections, it holds them open to reuse them.  If you want to close the connection to the database as soon as the end client closes it, then you should not use pgbouncer but just connect directly to the database.
